# Overloading [] and = operators to accept values for my template class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, data-structures, overloading

I am creating my own ArrayList STL class in C++ and now am stuck in a problem. I want to overload the [] or = operator (I'm sorry I don't know which one will be better implementation) such that the value on the right side of = operator gets assigned to the element of the vector accessed by the [] operator.

I have overloaded the [] operator to get the element from the array but don't know how to deal with assignment with it.

Here's the ArrayList class implementation :

```
template<class T> class ArrayList
{
   T* array;
   ArrayList() {}
   
   // Implemetation of [] overloading
   T& operator[] (int index) {return array[index];}
}
```

Comment: Your program will work after initializing `array` properly. What is your problem?

Comment: I don't see a point why you would want to create an `ArrayList` class while there's already `vector`s available in C++. If you need additional features, I would suggest extending the class and adding your features to it. Defining a class from scratch can easily lead to problems like memory leak which can be avoided with vectors.

Comment: Make it `T& operator[] (std::size_t index) {return array[index];}` and add the overload: `const T& operator[] const (std::size_t index) {return array[index];}` and you're home.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy - these are usually cases of people learning the language and/or general data structure concepts by implementing structures themselves. It is a valuable exercise, and one many of us have gone through ourselves. Once people have finished this learning process, I agree with you wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused. You are asking about assigning `T` objects but `T` is not your `ArrayList` class. It's up to the `T` class to handle it's own assignment, not upto your `ArrayList` class.

The code you have written already will work fine.

```
ArrayList<int> x = ...;
x[1] = 2;

ArrayList<std::string> y = ...;
y[0] = "hello";
```

Although you should make the `const` change that Ted mentioned in the comments.